# Timeout on "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"

Tags: php, mysql, timeout

My query was just fine but i needed to check if there are duplicates on the ID and date/time field so i used

```
mysqli_query($link, "
        INSERT INTO wsmdata VALUES ('', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['wsmID'])."',
 '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $a[0])." ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $a[1])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $a[2])."')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY
        UPDATE bar = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $a[2])."'") or die (mysqli_error($link));
```

I'm having a foreach loop that loops through all the uploaded files. It procese 1008 rows into the database but then i get:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\logsysteem\adddata.php on line 30
```

Comment: Can you post this query with your foreach loop? Your query looks okay.

Comment: Documentation - [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: If you're using `mysqli_real_escape_string`, you're doing it wrong. Please use [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to do your escaping. The way you're doing it, if you accidentally miss an escape call, your entire application can be destroyed by a SQL injection bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't set the time lime of your script.

You have two options to make it works :
1/ Use `set_time_limit()` at the top of your php script
2/ Change this value in your `php.ini` config file

If it's ponctually for a personnal script, i recommend you to use the first solution.

Edit : For further explications read this https://www.php.net/set_time_limit